# how to Add new payment gateway like First data payment in paid membership pro plugin of wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, firstdata

I want to add first data payment gateway in **paid membership pro plugin** of wordpress.

I researched following site:-
http://www.paidmembershipspro.com/2013/04/adding-a-new-payment-gateway-option-to-paid-memberships-pro/

it says that "Create a new plugin to house your gateway addon." but how to create it and where to create it..
please explian me in brief...

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer from Kimberly Coleman a Co-founder of the PMP plugin :

> The core Paid Memberships Pro plugin should not be modified. Your
>   gateway should be a separate plugin in its own folder in the
>   wp-content/plugins folder of your site. Note that the way gateways are
>   integrated with Paid Memberships Pro is being revamped with v1.8 – to
>   be released soon. This will make the process of adding gateways a bit
>   simpler / more modular.

Comment: Hi there! Please consider posting a link to the resource where the quote was taken just as added info to your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the 1.8 version came out a while back, the documentation for adding a gateway to Paid Memberships Pro has also been updated. There's a skeleton example gateway you can build from as well, and I've always found the forum-based support responsive, too.

The place to start on the PMPro site is http://www.paidmembershipspro.com/gateway/adding-a-new-gateway/ - you'll find those resources there.